# Undefined array key 1 Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, eloquent, laravel-8

I am having this problem in visualizing, through a card, the elements present in the db.

This is the controller:

**Controller.php**

```
    class PublicController extends Controller
    {
        public function homepage(){
            $articles = Article::all();
            //dd(compact('articles'));
            return view('welcome', compact('articles'));
        }

    }
```

and this is the view:

**welcome.php**

```
    @foreach {$articles as $article}
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{$article->title}}</h5>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                            <p class="card-text">{{$article->description}}</p>
                            <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                            <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
```

This is the *error* that appears to me:

**Undefined array key 1**

[image: Undefined array key 1]

Comment: ``View::make('welcome')->with(compact('articles'))`` also in blade use parantheses `(` instead of brackets `{`

Comment: Please use  triple `  at the beginning and at the end of your code instead of the code snippet option in your case (because this code can't be executed/tested like that). Full guide [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/1213575)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help centre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong type of brackets/parentheses here:

```
@foreach {$articles as $article}
```

It should be like this:

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
```

Comment: thank you. It was a very trivial thing that escaped me